# How to convert old website to responsive without losing traffic

Tags: responsive-design

I’m not a technical expert. We have an old website that was built between 2000 and 2006, it is not responsive. I was told by a few people that it is not worth it to fix the website because there are too many pages and it will be very hard to do. The good thing is that the website is ranking very high for certain many hard to get keywords and we don’t want to lose the ranking when we switch to a modern responsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="An online lending marketplace that connects borrowers, brokers and lenders with its trading platform."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="land loan, commercial loan, private investor, private lenders, hard money loans, mobile home, commercial mortgage, refinancing, loan" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CONTENT-LANGUAGE" content="English" />
<meta name="RATING" content="General" />
<meta name="distribution" content="global" />
<meta name="copyright" content="2020, Lending Universe, Inc." />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="Window-target" content="_top" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.lendinguniverse.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.lendinguniverse.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css" />
<META name="PageID" content="1043">
<title>Hard Money Loans, Residential, Commercial & Land | Lending Universe</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function CheckValues() {
    if (!NonBlank(document.frmLogin.txtUsername, 'Username')) return false;
    if (!NonBlank(document.frmLogin.txtPassword, 'Password')) return false;

    return true;
}
function ShowMembershipBenefits()
{
    var w = 485;
    var h = 540;
    var features = "left=60,top=30,width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes";
    window.open("BorrowersMembershipBenefits.asp", "", features);
}

function GetInstantQuote()
{
    window.document.location = 'Borrowers.asp'
}

//-->
</script>


</head>
```

What can be done without losing traffic? Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you believe "converting" the website will result in lost traffic?

Answer (score 0):

Responsive design is the use of CSS to modify the visual behavior of the html so that when the width of the screen shrinks (such as going to a smaller computer, tablet or phone) the content will move and change size to be more readable.

This usually means removing tables and using divs with pixel break points to have content drop below or be hidden on smaller screens.  It is more advanced than this but this is the very basics.

None of this changes your content and should not effect any of traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! We have over 1000 pages and old programming code many of the pages are .asp . Can you or anyone recommend a solution to convert the old website into a responsive website?

Comment: asp.net is your backend and other than the html structure does not affect your front end.  You should have a global css file usually and im sure more specialty cases thier own css files.  You will modify those to make the site reponsive and change the visual nature of your site based on the media-type width.  you should not need to modify your html much to do this in most cases.